How to force Mouse Pointer to be visible for app that has hidden it
I'm trying to make the Mouse Pointer visible for an app that has hidden it.
I don't have access to the source for this app, (PoS kiosk, with a broken touchscreen), hence I need to be able to see and use the mouse.
I've tried writing an MFC dialog app that calls ShowCursor(true), but it seems that this only affects the visibility of the cursor for the app that has called it.
Is there anyway to get the mouse pointer to show again for the kiosk app?, maybe by getting a handle to it or using SendMessage/Postmessage ? or some way to make ShowCursor apply to all apps.

Set up a global mouse hook using SetWindowsHookEx to monitor mouse events and force the cursor to reappear.

You can use Microsoft Detours to monkey-patch the Windows APIs.  That way you could intercept the app's call to hide the cursor.

@Eljay since this is in a kiosk situation, the kiosk app is likely to be run and hide the cursor before the OP's app is run.

I would try injecting code into the kiosk app process and then call ShowCursor(true) from that injected code.

https://pastebin.com/raw/FuZn8P7G would something like that do?
